# modal pop window backdrop static not working

Tags: bootstrap, commandlink, modal, static

I have bootstrap modal pop-up window. I want the background to be non-clickable. I have close button to close the modal pop-up, so the users should use only that.  Clicking outside the modal pop-up window also closes the pop-up.

I'm trying to restrict it by using **html-data-backdrop="static"** in the CommandLink but still not working.

Here's the code I'm referring to.

```
<apex:commandLink value="" action="{!mySearch.retrieveVideo}" rerender="apVideoTrigger" html-data-backdrop="static" oncomplete="openvideo();">
      <apex:param name="pt_id" value="{!pt.eng.Id}"/>
      <i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> 
</apex:commandLink>
```

And the scripts

```
function openvideo(){
    j$('#apvideo').modal();
    videojs('#videoPt');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try passing in the backdrop option into the modal method

```
j$('#apvideo').modal({backdrop:'static'});
```

check the [bootstrap modal reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options) for all the available options

Comment: Amazing, it works.  Thank you for the link.  I used 'keyboard:false' too to prevent closing the window using ESC key.